# Asus laptop clean install

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning

The title might be a bit low on information but I couldn't make up my mind on how to explain the issue in one line.

I want to install a clean Windows 8.1 on my Asus laptop. Everything is ready to go, but I am currently stuck with doubt when going for the Custom Install option. I have to repartition my drives but there are currently 7 partitions showing (yes, 7!):

1. System (100MB)
2. Recovery (900MB)
3. x (MSR, Reserved, 128MB
4. OS (186GB)
5. x (Recovery, 350MB)
6. Data (258,3GB)
7. Restore (20GB)

Some research showed that the [MSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition) doesn't appear to hold any data required by the OS. The OS and Data partitions are also clear to me, one for the OS and one for other data. Restore seems to hold a copy of the OS incase you would want to reset back to factory.

My issue seems to lie with the two recovery and the system-partitions. Also, if the MSR is actually required or I haven't fully understood its meaning, what is this used for?

What is the purpose of each of these partitions and which are safe to be formatted and possibly deleted for the clean install?

Comment: Do you wish to remove Windows 7 completely and install windows 8.1? If the answer is yes, then you can safetly format OS partition and install 8.1 there

Comment: I know I can reformat the OS partition, I am more in doubt of the other partitions. See my edited question.

Comment: All the MSR contains is the WINRe image which is the same environment you get when you boot to a windows installtion disk

Comment: If you use `OS` partition for your 8.1 installation, the other partitions will not be affected. Once the 8.1 is installed and your system is up and running you can possibly remove the other unwanted partitions one by one. I would recommend against removing partitions before a successful installation

Comment: I also know the other partitions will not be effected. What I want to know is whether it is safe to delete them beforehand, so I can have say 2 partitions, one OS and one Data. In other words, are the others required for regular behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the partitions, then create one partition. The installer will tell you it will create some extra partitions to get all the needed functionality, let it do it.

I don't remember exactly but I think you end up with 2 or 3 partitions if you have a BIOS and 4 or 5 if you have a UEFI.

You can create your partitions outside of the installer so that you don't have the extra partitions, but they are required if you want to enable BitLocker encryption later.